# Is making an always running wordpress plugin possible?

Tags: php, wordpress, web-applications, trading

I'm currently creating a trading bot which should constantly check the bitcoin market and buy/sell bitcoins when bitcoin reaches a determinate value.

I'm building a Wordpress plugin and I would like the application constantly running on my website, even when the user is disconnected.
Is that possible? Is it possible to make my application running on the server 24/7?

I'm using PHP.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: keyword: "cronjob"

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion I've found out there is a Wordpress function called wp_cron. If you know it, do you think it is possible to run some php code inside a plugin every scheduled time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about WP, but php doesn't run like that.  You'd need a cron or a supervisor.